# Doesn't nuxt 3 support the builder design pattern for composables?

Tags: inheritance, vuejs3, builder, nuxt3, composable

I've recently known about nuxt 3 (literally a few days ago), became excited about it and started to migrate one of my vue project to it. Unfortunately, there is a problem, which I can't solve - for some reason code which implements a builder design pattern works on pure vue 3, but doesn't work on nuxt 3.

The simplified example looks like this - suppose that we have a class `Foo`, for which we want to implement the builder pattern. This file is located at `composables/Foo.ts`:

```
import SuperFoo from './SuperFoo'

export default class Foo extends SuperFoo {
  constructor (bar: string) {
    super(bar)
  }

  static build({ bar }: { bar: string }) {
    return new Foo(
      bar
    )
  }
}
```

Then, we have a base class `SuperFoo`, located at `composables/SuperFoo.ts`:

```
export default class SuperFoo {
  bar = 'baz'

  constructor (bar: string) {
    this.bar = bar
  }
}
```

Finally, we have a file `composables/index.ts` which contains the export declaration for auto-imports:

```
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'
```

So, having all these files on disk, now if we execute command `npm run build`, we will see the following exception if we build the app using `webpack` or `vite` builder (the example is provided for the webpack builder):

```
 WARN  Duplicated imports "Foo", the one from "/home/zeio/nuxt/2amar/composables/Foo.ts" has been ignored                                                                                                                         8:59:45 PM


 ERROR  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                                                                                                          8:59:48 PM

  Module parse failed: Identifier 'Foo' has already been declared (4:21)
  File was processed with these loaders:
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/esbuild-loader/dist/index.cjs
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | "use strict";
  | import SuperFoo from "./SuperFoo";
  > export default class Foo extends SuperFoo {
  |   constructor(bar) {
  |     super(bar);
  @ ./composables/index.ts 3:0-39 3:0-39
  @ ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Acomposable-keys!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Adynamic-base-path!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Atree-shake-composables%3Atransform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=unctx%3Atransform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aimports-transform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Acomponents-loader!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Acomponents%3Aimports!./node_modules/esbuild-loader/dist/index.cjs??clonedRuleSet-4!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0]!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aclient-fallback-auto-id!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aserver-devonly%3Atransform!./app.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts
  @ ./app.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=ts 1:0-1077 1:0-1077 1:1078-2144 1:1078-2144
  @ ./app.vue 1:0-65 2:0-60 2:0-60 6:20-26
  @ ./.nuxt/app-component.mjs 1:0-56 1:0-56
  @ ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Adynamic-base-path!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Atree-shake-composables%3Atransform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=unctx%3Atransform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aimports-transform!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Acomponents-loader!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Acomponents%3Aimports!./node_modules/esbuild-loader/dist/index.cjs??clonedRuleSet-4!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0]!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aclient-fallback-auto-id!./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js?unpluginName=nuxt%3Aserver-devonly%3Atransform!./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js
  @ ./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js 1:0-959 1:0-959 1:960-1908 1:960-1908
  @ ./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue 1:0-71 2:0-66 2:0-66 4:20-26
  @ ./.nuxt/root-component.mjs
  @ ./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.js 7:0-54 43:40-53 43:67-80
  
  client compiled with 1 error
```

Am I using `nuxt` incorrently, or what's wrong with my example?

I've tried to exclude inheritance and self constructor call from the code separately, it seems that the error appers only when we have both of them. I've expected that there won't be any build errors.

Actually, there was a build error, saying that class `Foo` is declared twice, but in fact it isn't. Seems that there is possibly a problem of imports, but I don't understand what's wrong in particular - there aren't any circular dependencies, generated file `.nuxt/imports.d.ts` also looks fine, it contains two statements related to classes from the example:

```
export { default as SuperFoo } from '../composables/SuperFoo';
export { Foo } from '../composables/index';
```

If we make file `composables/index.ts` empty to avoid duplicated imports, then the build completes without exceptions, but it is an extremely constrained solution which doesn't work for classes located in nested folders. The conclusion is that we should store all classes in the root `composables` folder, which is feasible only for small projects, but is there a more flexible solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved by using `nuxt.config.js` to make the builder scan nested folders instead of relying on `index.ts`:

```
...
  imports: {
    dirs: [
      'composables',
      'composables/foo'
    ]
  },
...
```